# Jquery select element by index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

There is my markup:

```
<UL style="-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0" class="ui-tabs ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" sizcache="3" sizset="5">
  <LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" jQuery1280326216622="3" sizcache="3" sizset="5">
    <A href="#tab_1" jQuery1280326216622="4"><SPAN>Page 1n</SPAN></A>
  </LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active" jQuery1280326216622="5" sizcache="3" sizset="6">
    <A href="#tab_2" jQuery1280326216622="6"><SPAN>Page 2</SPAN></A>
  </LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" jQuery1280326216622="7" sizcache="3" sizset="7">
    <A href="#tab_3" jQuery1280326216622="8"><SPAN>Page 3</SPAN></A>
  </LI>
  <LI class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" jQuery1280326216622="9" sizcache="3" sizset="8">
    <A href="#tab_4" jQuery1280326216622="10"><SPAN>Page 4</SPAN></A>
  </LI>
</UL>
```

and the js code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery(".ui-layout-center").tabs({   show: loadIframe });

        rootLayout = jQuery('#container').layout
       ({
           applyDefaultStyles: true,
           north__spacing_open: 0
       });

        jQuery("#tabs_div").tabs();
        loadIframe();
    });
function reciveDataFromPages(tabIndex, data) {
       //do some thing
}
```

how i can active the tab with the 
index: tabIndex
and 
url : data

Any ideas???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `:eq()`, eg:

```
$(".ui-tabs a").removeClass("active");
$(".ui-tabs a:eq("+tabIndex+")").addClass("active");
```

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: I have the following error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @Haroldis: which version of jQuery are you using, which version of IE and which file/line does the error point to?

Comment: You could also use `$(".ui-tabs a").eq(tabIndex)` rather than `$(".ui-tabs a:eq("+tabIndex+")")`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a tab selected based upon the tab index returned in the function receiveDataFromPages, why can't you just do this:

```
$(".ui-layout-center").tabs("option", "selected", tabIndex);
```

I'm not sure why the URL matters in the determination of the selected tab.  I may not fully understand the question, though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does it work now that you changed `JQuery` to `$`?  It's probably better to go through the jQueryUI API to manipulate state.  This way you're insured in case they change class names in later releases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:nth-child(youIndex)` in your selector.